# How to write a query which recursively returns all foreign key references to a column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, foreign-key

I need to obtain a list of foreign keys which refer to a given column, as well as all foreign keys which refer to those keys, and so on. Order does not matter. I have

```
SELECT
    s.name,
    t.name,
    c.name,
    fk.name
FROM
    sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk
        ON fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c
        ON c.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
        AND c.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t
        ON t.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
        ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE
    fkc.referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MyTable')
    AND fkc.referenced_column_id = (
        SELECT TOP 1
            column_id
        FROM
            sys.columns
        WHERE
            name = 'MyColumn'
            AND object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MyTable')
    )
```

However, this just returns the foreign keys which immediately reference the column, not the entire tree of foreign keys referencing this column.

Comment: Can you give an example of why you would have a relationship like this? I can understand tables that reference tables that in turn reference other tables, but I'm having a hard time envisioning a real-world entity that would have cascading references from table to table using the same column. Can you give some idea what kind of tables would have a primary key that is both referenced by a foreign key and references a different primary key?

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive CTE, it's essentially no different to the examples that involve `HumanResources.Employee`, except that you're joining across more tables. Instead of `EmployeeID`s, you're collecting `object_id` and `column_id` combinations.